# JW Player creating playlist on the fly

Tags: javascript, jwplayer

I am attempting to create a playlist on the fly based on the example shown in the documentation: (http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/jw-player-for-flash-v5/16026/loading-a-playlist-into-the-player)

```
    jwplayer("presentation").setup({
        flashplayer: "/javascripts/jwplayer/player.swf",
        height: 270,
        width: 580,
        file: files[0],
        'playlist.position': "right",
        'playlist.size': 100
    });

    for (var k=1;k<files.length;k++)
    {
        var playlist = jwplayer().getPlaylist();
            var newItem = {
                file: files[k],
                title: files[k]
            };
            playlist.push(newItem);
            jwplayer().load(playlist);
    }
```

The error I receive is:
TypeError: Result of expression 's' [undefined] is not an object.

which seems to be caused by var playlist = jwplayer().getPlaylist();

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling `jwplayer("presentation").load(playlist);` instead.

Also, you should probably avoid calling the `getPlaylist` and `load` methods every time you enter the loop. Better yet, consider updating your `files` array so you can just do a `playlist.concat(files)` instead of the loop.

```
var playlist = jwplayer().getPlaylist();
for (var k=1;k<files.length;k++)
{
        var newItem = {
            file: files[k],
            title: files[k]
        };
        playlist.push(newItem);
}
jwplayer("presentation").load(playlist);
```

Comment: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/31800/loading-new-playlists/

To dynamically load playlist